# After importing products Successful data not display frontend due to cataloginventory_stock_status in magento2

Tags: magento2, import

After importing product my product doesn't display frontend.
I have debugged for it and I have found that my record not updated in ***cataloginventory_stock_status*** table.

I have reindexed after importing products.

Comment: Add stock qty  for products

Comment: All the stock related data imported
out_of_stock_qty
is_in_stock
use_config_notify_stock_qty
manage_stock
use_config_manage_stock
let me know if i am missing anything